# Showing the last login time of when a user logs into their Gmail account

Tags: gmail

How do I find out the last login time of a user of a consumer account (myself) when they log into their Gmail account?

I don't see this information at all.

Comment: Is this for a google apps domain?  Or are you talking about regular accounts?

Comment: It was for regular accounts, I am aware of the Google Apps admin page where he can lookup this information for the rest of the users in the domain.

Answer (score 4):

If it’s your own account, there’s a line in each page footer reading “Last account activity: 0 minutes ago at IP 111.222.333.444. Details” — click the “Details” link.

If it’s a Google Apps account and you’re a domain administrator the last login date/time of each user is displayed in the Apps control panel (“Manage this domain” in the top right hand corner of any GApps service page).

Otherwise, this information isn’t available to you.

Answer (score 2):

Scroll to the bottom of your Gmail page. At the bottom-right corner, notice the *Last account activity: X ago*. You may click details to know about the devices you have used. Although, you can see the exact time only for the logins done today.

Answer (score 1):

If you are logged in, one of the last lines of the web interface is  "last account activity" or something. I guess that's what you are looking for.

Comment: I' m assuming he means someone other than himself, Samuel can you confirm please.

Comment: From my GMail account:
Last account activity: x hours ago on this computer.  ''Details''
The Details button provides source IP's and times for recent account activity.

Comment: I was looking for the Last account activity details, somehow I missed it.

Comment: @Chopper3 - I was looking for information for the user who logs in (i.e. myself in this case). I am aware of the Google Apps administrator option, who has a admin page where he looks up this information.

Answer (score -1):

Um...depends. I suppose you could look at your proxy logs if you have it. Maybe there's a log setting for DNS records. If you're just asking this to find out when a friend or relative last checked their mail, you'll probably get migrated to SuperUser.